# Total value with jquery on table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to calculate the total on the table using jquery, but when run totals do not appear. so I want to show the total live when I enter the input value, total auto-summing, what's wrong?

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed">                                   
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left"><strong>Product</strong></td>
            <td class="text-center"><strong>Value</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                 
        <tr>
            <td>Microwave</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_a" name="producta" value="12.000"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Microwave</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_b" name="producta" value="19.000"></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Microwave</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_c" name="producta" value="15.000"></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="thick-line"><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td class="thick-line"><input type="text" id="total" name="total" /></td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var total = ($('#product_a').val() + $('#product_b').val() + $('#product_c').val()) ;
    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

Comment: What are you getting as your answer? You might try surrounding the .val() statements with parseInt, like parseInt($('#product_a').val())

Comment: thanks @NickWinner that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. `val()` returns a string on an `input[type=text]` and currently you're just concatenating string values.

> I want to show the total live when I enter the input value

Then, you need to add a listener when the inputs are being changed as you type. This could be done with `keyup` event.

**E.g.**

```js
$(function() {
  var $aProduct = $('#product_a'),
    $bProduct = $('#product_b'),
    $cProduct = $('#product_c'),
    $total = $('#total'),
    runTotal = function() {
      var a = parseInt($aProduct.val()),
        b = parseInt($bProduct.val()),
        c = parseInt($cProduct.val());

      $total.val(a + b + c);
    };

  $('.inputVal').on('keyup', runTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><strong>Product</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><strong>Value</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Microwave</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="product_a" name="producta" class="inputVal" value="12.000">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Microwave</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="product_b" name="productb" class="inputVal" value="19.000">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Microwave</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="product_c" name="productc" class="inputVal" value="15.000">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="thick-line"><strong>Total</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="thick-line">
        <input type="text" id="total" name="total" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @choz, really like my expectations, but why not directly summed when refreshed, so it must be replaced before its value?

Comment: @irwandwiyanto You can do it yourself, by calling `runTotal` function when refreshed..

Answer (score 1):

Hi try following code....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").on("change",updateTotal); // this will total on change input.
    updateTotal(); //this will total on start..
});


function updateTotal()
{
   var total = ($('#product_a').val()*1 + $('#product_b').val()*1 + $('#product_c').val()*1) ;
    //By multiplying 1 to any string format number it will convert to number datatype.


    //var total = (Number($('#product_a').val()) + Number($('#product_b').val()) + Number($('#product_c').val()));
    //You can also uncomment above line to get your desire output.


    $('#total').val(total);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, you could also just use the parseInt function, may be a bit cleaner :)

Comment: @NickWinner : there is also short cut by simply multiplying with 1  ;-) or `Number($('#product_a').val())`

Comment: thanks @spankajd, it can be used, but how to automatically summed?

Comment: Or you can use `+$('#product_a').val()` to coerce it to a number.

Comment: @Terry sorry.. what u want to say?